# Spring @Query with two Joins

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create @Query, witch will return json structure with one Database query. But Unfortunately I am getting error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to org...entity.MainCategory

```
@Entity
class MainCategory(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    var id: Long = -1,
    ...
    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "maincategory", cascade = [(CascadeType.ALL)], 
fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var sub_category: List<SubCategory> = emptyList()
)

@Entity
class SubCategory(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0,
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "maincategory_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    val maincategory: MainCategory,

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "subcategory", cascade = [(CascadeType.ALL)], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var topics: List<Topic> = emptyList()
)

@Entity
class Topic (@Id
         @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
         val id: Long = 0,
         ...
         @ManyToOne
         @JsonIgnore
         @JoinColumn(name = "subcategory_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         val subcategory: SubCategory,

         @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
         @JoinColumn(name = "tpc_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName="ID")
         var posts: List<Post>
)

@Repository
interface MainCategoryRepository : CrudRepository<MainCategory, Long> {
@Query("FROM MainCategory m LEFT JOIN FETCH m.sub_category s LEFT JOIN s.topics")
fun findList(): MutableIterable<MainCategory>
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("mainCategory")
class MainCategoryController(val mainCategoryRepository: MainCategoryRepository) {
@GetMapping("/findList")
fun findList(): MutableIterable<MainCategory> {
    val i: MutableIterable<MainCategory> =  this.mainCategoryRepository.findList()
    i.forEach{it.sub_category.forEach{ cs ->
        cs.topics.forEach{it ->
            it.posts = emptyList()}
    }
    }
    return i
}
}
```

Is there a possibility to return MainCategory & SubCategory & Topics with only One query?

Comment: A standard JPQL query starts with `select`. Add `select distinct m` at the beginning of the query. Note that your last LEFT JOIN is completely useless, since it doesn' have FETCH.

Comment: After I change query to "SELECT DISTINCT m FROM MainCategory m LEFT JOIN FETCH m.sub_category s LEFT JOIN FETCH s.topics" I am getting "org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags" error

Comment: Ok, I solved problem by changing in entities List to Set. Many thanks @JBNizet